# WebSphere MQ customization : insert latency

Tags: ibm-mq

I'm trying to insert some latency in my WebSphere MQ messaging system for some testing purposes. That is, after an application has put a message in a queue, I don't want it to be immediatelly available to the receiving application. If transfering from a queue to another, I would have written a program with a sleep() function in between transfers.

Is there an easy way to do that with MQ Exits as opposed to writing some e.g. Java code that connects to the QM and does the job?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what type of latency you want to introduce and where in the process you want to introduce this?

Comment: Basically I would like to simulate network latency. I updated the question.

Comment: The simplest solution would be to put to a second queue and have a simple program reading messages from that queue and then delaying before putting to the queue read by the receiving application.

Comment: You may be able to use the q or qload program for this purpose.  IBM released the source for both on github.  MQGem Software has a supported version of qload with many enhancments as well.

Comment: Did you have a look at MQ Channel Throttler? ( http://www.capitalware.com/mqct_overview.html ) You can set it to allow only 1 message per second or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is "Delivery Delay" feature from MQ v8.0 onwards where you can specify a delivery delay when sending a message. The queue manager does not deliver the message until after the specified delivery delay has elapsed. See here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q119200_.htm